# Cannot start wifi hotspot after installing gnome

Tags: networking, wireless, gnome, kubuntu

I tried using Kubuntu 19.10 for a while, and in the end I decided I liked the gnome desktop enviroment better. So rather than doing another clean install, I just ran `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to get Gnome.

However, now I can't start a wifi hotspot. I was able to do it from KDE, and I was able to do it on previous Ubuntu installs, but something about installing gnome over Kubuntu has made it so when I try to start it, it disconnects from the wifi, tries for a second, and then connects back to the wifi network with no error message.

Comment: The subset of users who have both desktops installed and able to help you is probably rather small. If you haven't invested too much effort already, I suggest backing your valuable data and doing a clean install.

Comment: I wanted to avoid a clean install since ubuntu 20.04 is coming out at the end of the month already and I did plan to do the clean install there. But I posted now because I have no clue how to even begin to troubleshoot

Comment: Fair enough! My point is just that troubleshooting a system with two DEs could be complicated.